# io.to(room).emit('player-movement-update', data);

Tags: node.js, socket.io

working on a project using socket.io in node js. I am facing a issue

io.to(room).emit('player-movement-update', data);

io.to is not broadcasting the event and data to all the users in the room. I read socketio documentation but didn't get any help. If anyone of you can help, it will be kind

Comment: try io.to(room).emit('player-movement-update', data);

Answer (score 0):

the room was returning as integer for 1st time than sting that's why i was facing issue.
I used:
room = "room_"+room

this always return sting,